# Does Veigar's Baleful Strike (Q) need to land the killing blow on a champion to gain AP or is it passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

The tool tip is very vague in its description. I know you need to kill a minion with Q to gain AP, but how does it interact with champions?

Answer (score 8):

> **BaleFul Strike:**
>
> (Passive): Veigar gains bonus ability power for each
> champion kill from any damage source. Ability Power Gain per Champion
> Kill: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5
>
> (Active): Unleashes dark energy at target enemy, dealing magic damage.
> If this ability deals a killing blow, Veigar gains 1 ability power.

You only need to kill the enemy champion to get the passive AP increase. You will however also get an additional AP increase from last hitting that champion using Baleful Strike.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Veigar_the_Tiny_Master_of_Evil

Answer (score 1):

Against champs, you do not need to last hit with Baleful Strike for an AP bonus.  It automatically gives you a set amount equal to Baleful Strike's level.  If you last hit with it, you also gain the one from the active.

Answer (score -2):

Veigar's Baleful Strike only gets stacks when it deals a killing blow on either champions or minions/monsters.

Answer (score -3):

It has to get the killing blow.

Answer (score -3):

Do not listen to any of these fools about the killing blow for champions. I don't know why they don't read up abilities now a days or keep with patches, but to get the extra ability power from champions you must kill a champion from ANY DAMAGE SOURCE! It is a passive from his q the more you lvl up your q the more ability power you get from kills, but you no longer need to last hit with your q to get the ability power form champions.

However you do you need to last hit creeps with your q to get the 1 extra ability power.